# Launchctl not unloading Apache

Tags: macos, apache, osx-lion, launchd

I ran `sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist` and it unloads apache. But when I reboot, apache is back up and running. How do I permanently remove Apache from starting on boot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently I need to study the manual. It needs the `-w` flag to override the Disabled key as found in the man page for `launchctl`